# Nvidia 3d acceleration for Nvidia 620M (Kali Linux {Debian})?NOTWORKING?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati, xorg

i'm currently learning linux but i'm familiar with Computers.
I am using Kali 32bit i386 2.0 with kernel 4.3.--(BASED ON DEBIAN) my problem is i can't play games with wine on the high speed as i could on my windows 7.
I searched and found out There is no proper driver for nvidia Gpu comes installed. 
I have Nvidia-620-M model gpu with 3d acceleration and when i run **glxinfo | grep OpenGL** it shows like this [Something like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DC13.png)

It tells me i am using Intel GPU instead of nvidia one which can be possible because my intel card also can work as GPU.**i know because i installed once intel gpu drivers on my windows 7 and all the programs (including games like max payne 3) switched from nvidia to intel but couldn't run in proper speed cuz i guess my intel gpu doesn't have proper 3d acceleration.**

So i want to know how can i make my nvidia gpu 3d acceleration properly work? everything else in my pc working fine.

ThanksInAdvance.

edit:**i currently have noveau driver for my nvidia gpu which was preinstalled.**

**lspci** shows this.
[Please check .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMW0.png)

Comment: what does this command 'lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' does?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd GeForce GT 620M
 Kernel modules: nouveau
@Ashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) nvidia-361 is the driver for 620

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...In your case i am seeing it's not there but just to be on the safer side.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run`
and follow the on screen instructions

**Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu...**

Comment: Thankyou so much! ! i will try it but i am using debian not ububtu i know you want me to edit the boot method so the nvidia adapter is disabled which is correct cuz last time i tried installing nvidia drivers it just killed my whole system.Gnome login screen(gdm3) wasn't loading up. i can follow your instructions but i want to ask can i install nvidia-driver from synaptic after purgin current drivers?

Comment: it's worth trying...in case it doesn't work then you can do sudo apt-get purge nvidia*. The one you are installing from ppa is the opensource nvidia driver...working fine on two machines for me(950M and 610). M is for laptop variants.

Comment: How can i install from ppa repositories on debian? @ashu

Comment: @Hitesh. This site is specific to Ubuntu Linux. But refer to this link 'https://wiki.debian.org/CreatePackageFromPPA' My disclaimer...i haven't tried this in Debian Linux