# Problem installing Ubuntu 15.10 on ASUS R510JX

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, nvidia, 15.10

I recently bought an ASUS R510JX-DM302T with the following main hardware:

- Processor: i7-4750HQ
- RAM: 8GB DDR3L 1600MHz
- HDD: 1TB 5400rpm
- NVIDIA GTX 950M

The laptop came with W10 and I want to install Ubuntu 15.10 (or 14.04) alongside. The thing is before the start of the installation, the process freezes on the loading window (Ubuntu logo with the dots). Trying it more times (with other distro 14.04 to see if this was the problem) I got a black screen with several quick error-like messages showing "nouveau" continuously with another one stating kernel panic at the end.

I hope this information is enough to get some help as I am completely new to Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do the solutions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/608532/205638) or [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425093/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-10-if-hardware-doesnt-support-nouveau-video-driver) help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) nvidia-361 is the driver for GTX 950M(same as in my other laptop).

Ctrl+Alt+T and then login to the tty

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-3

Similar kind of solution i have provided in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739218/nvidia-3d-acceleration-for-nvidia-620m-kali-linux-debiannotworking/739220#739220)

Comment: Hi Ashu,

Firstly thank you so much for the quick and detailed solution. However I am embarrased to be blocked in the first step. 

I understand that you believe that I managed to install Ubuntu (and thus that I can open a terminal window with the Ctrl+Alt+T command) but I cannot do so as the errors occur prior to the installation process and so I have only W10 and the GRUB menu available. 

I supose however that there must be a way out or that I am not fully understanding your answer.

Anyhow, thank you in advance.

Comment: @Dreoasteh. You can refer to this link(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) to pass on the boot params during install from live USB.